# Using the same workspace.xml on different computers

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv, jetbrains-ide

I'm syncing a project folder between two computers, one Mac and one Ubuntu machine. The interpreters I'm using on both of these computers are located under the same path. Thus I configured the `.idea/workspace.xml` file as follows:

```
  <option name="SDK_HOME" value="$USER_HOME$/<some_path>">
```

Hoping this would work for both of the computers.

This works fine for the Mac PC, and then I synced the configured `.xml` file to the Ubuntu Machine. I did this by: (1) Delete the `.xml` file on the Ubuntu Machine. (2) Sync it using github.

However, when I ran/debugged the corresponding `.py` file, in the console it still points to the previous configured interpreter path.

I wonder if there's some configuration elsewhere that has higher priority to the `workspace.xml` file?

What should I do to make the configured `workspace.xml` taking effect on the Ubuntu machine as well?

Comment: What interpreter do you see when you actually run/debug the `.py` file, not in the console?

Answer (score 0):

The console interpreter isn't necessarily the same as the project's run/debug interpreter.

It can be independently configured via `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Console` -> `Python Console` (at least on my older PyCharm 5.0 Pro version).

Which, when configured, apparently translates inside `.idea/workspace.xml` into a

```
<console-settings ... sdk-home="<some_path>" ...>`
```

versus, when left at default, a

```
<console-settings ... is-module-sdk="true" ...>`
```

Side note: in general version-controlling `.idea/workspace.xml` is not recommended if multiple developers work on the project because it contains user specific settings. From [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)

> If you decide to share IDE project files with other developers, follow
>   these guidelines:
>
> **Directory based project format (.idea directory)**
>
> This format is used by all the recent IDE versions by default. Here is
>   what you need to share:
>
> - All the files under .idea directory in the project root **except** the **workspace.xml**, **usage.statistics.xml**, and **tasks.xml**
>     files which store user specific settings